# How to use axios instance in different components in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have created an axios instance:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.io/api/',
  timeout: 1000
});
```

and would like to use it on different components.
My webapp is secured with Keycloak and every request that goes to API, needs an authentication token. To get the token, I call the Keycloak method as follows:

```
    kc
        .init({onLoad: "login-required"})
        .then(authenticated => {
            if (kc.idToken === undefined) {
                return Promise.reject("Can not be authenticated")
            }
            return authenticated && root !== null ? start({authToken: kc.idToken}, root) : Promise.reject("Can not be authenticated")
        })
        .catch(console.log)
```

When I do the request to the API server, I pass the token as `Bearer token` in the request header. To avoid passing the token on every request, can I use the [intercepter](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) right or what do I have to do?

Comment: I thinks instance part is fine. You just need to use interception. It seems like you are already managing token. Simple call in interceptor and use it there.

Answer (score 9):

One way to achieve this is as follows:

Create a file with the following code snippet and name this `httpService.js` (choose the name of your choice).

```
import axios from 'axios';    

// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${your_token}`;
    // OR config.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${your_token}`;
    config.baseURL = 'https://example.io/api/';

    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default {
  get: axios.get,
  post: axios.post,
  put: axios.put,
  delete: axios.delete,
  patch: axios.patch
};
```

Now to use it in other parts of your application, add this import:

```
import http from './httpService';
```

Example usage:

```
static getClient = (clientId) => {
    return http.get('/clients/' + clientId);
};
```

The `baseUrl` and `Authorization` header will be automatically configured with every request.

Answer (score 0):

Axios default configuration can be modified, once you modify the defaults all the service call that made using axios will use the same configuration.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}`;
```

Please refer to the official docs https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults